# Ipython notebook on 2 columns

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to have to have cells of a python notebook on 2 columns, for writng annotations next to code (for example, instead of inserting 2 cells below, I would insert I insert a cell on the right and a cell below on the left)
I know that it's possible to use custom css for changing the appearance (e.g https://github.com/nsonnad/base16-ipython-notebook/blob/master/ipython-3/output/base16-3024-dark.css ), is it possible also for the layout?

On the other hand, I found an example of how to use the css for creating a table layout (https://pixelsvsbytes.com/2012/02/this-css-layout-grid-is-no-holy-grail/), but not being very familiar with CSS I don't understand if this can be applied to an unknown number of equal blocks (unknown because they are generated interactively by the user). For reference, here is how currrently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just change the cells to markdown or raw and make them float right.

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("<style> div.code_cell{width: 75%;float: left;}"
    +"div.text_cell{width: 25%;float: right;}"
    +"div.text_cell div.prompt {display: none;}</style>")
```

Now when you enter a cell and want it on the right press esc-r (or m).
esc- unselects it and allows the notebook to process commands.  r is the command to make a raw cell.

[image]

Comment: Nice! It seems to be just what I need (except the fact that a header would be smaller on the right, but it's not a big problem)

Comment: You can't put a header on the left now and they'll still be the same size as before.  The markdown is a text cell is just moved right.  You could have the markdown move back left after rendering(ctrl-enter) by changing to `div.text_cell.unrendered` as raw never gets rendered.  Then it will be 100% width and you can put headers anywhere.

Comment: Hi, I try the code and it won't stop running.

Comment: @June The code isn't really running, it just changes the style of the notebook.  To change it back, delete the cell and reload the notebook.